# How to assign user and user.profile to the request object using a single database query in django?

Tags: django, database, authentication, django-models, django-middleware

Django assign user to request in the *django.contrib.auth.middleware.py* by calling

`request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))`

The *get_user* function is in the *init.py* file which in turns calls another *get_user* function in the *backends.py*

```
def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            user = UserModel._default_manager.get(pk=user_id)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        return user if self.user_can_authenticate(user) else None
```

Here it is making a database call to get user by id. How can I get the user profile(related to user by a one to one field) in the same query and propagate it back so I can assign it to *request.profile*?

Answer (score 0):

Let's use select_related() to join tables and get both profile and user in a single query, for example:

```
def get_user(self, user_id):
    profile = Profile.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).select_related("user").first()
    if not profile:
        return None
    return profile if self.user_can_authenticate(user) else None
```